# XSLT param value

Tags: xslt

I want to pass position() of current "section" to the "body" template. So I assigned the current position() into variable "sectionPos".
But when it is proceed, then the param "pSectionPos" in the "section/body" template always contains number 1.

If I uncomment the row  in the template "section..." then param "pSectionPos" correctly contains 1 and then 2.

xml structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <content>
        <section type="__section_table_">
            <body>
                <item>
                </item>
                <item>
                </item>
            </body>
        </section>
        <section type="__section_table_">
            <body>
                <item>
                </item>
                <item>
                </item>
            </body>
        </section>
    </content>
</data>
```

xslt structure:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [
<!ENTITY newLine          "&#10;">
<!ENTITY tab              "&#9;">
]>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    >
<xsl:output method='html' standalone="yes" indent="yes" />

<!--root-->
<xsl:template match="/">
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>     
      </head>
      <body>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="//data/content" /> 
          <xsl:text>&newLine;</xsl:text>   
      </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<!--content part-->
<xsl:template match="content">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="section[contains(attribute::type,'__section_table_')]" /> 
</xsl:template>

<!--sections part-->
<xsl:template match="section[contains(attribute::type,'__section_table_')]">    
    <xsl:variable name="sectionPos" as="xs:integer" select="xs:integer(position())" />
    <!--xsl:text>&newLine;</xsl:text>   
    <xsl:text>&tab;&tab;</xsl:text>   
    <xsl:value-of select="$sectionPos" /> 
    <xsl:value-of select="' template-section'"/-->

    <xsl:apply-templates select="body" >
        <xsl:with-param name="pSectionPos" select="$sectionPos" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<!--section body-->
<xsl:template match="section/body">
    <xsl:param name="pSectionPos" />        
    <xsl:text>&newLine;</xsl:text>   
    <xsl:text>&tab;&tab;</xsl:text>   
    <xsl:value-of select="$pSectionPos"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="' template-body'"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thank you.

Comment: `position()` is not necessarily the position of the node in the XML, but the position of the node in the list of selected nodes (which may include whitespace nodes if you have done `<xsl:apply-templates />` and not stripped out whitespace). It would help if you showed a full version of your XSLT that demonstrates the problem (especially if you have a template matching `content`). Thanks!

Comment: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y9x/1 with `xsl:strip-space` added shows the numbers `1` and `2` for me, if I solely use the code you have shown incorporated into a stylesheet root element at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y9x then the numbers are `2` and `4` as the built-in templates doing `apply-templates` process the `section` elements together with any text node children. So please show a minimal but complete stylesheet that shows the number `1` two times, it all depends on how you process the ancestors, as Tim has already pointed out.

Comment: Thank you for your comments/answer. 
I simplified my source xsl and updated it here. 
The output is:
  1 template-body
  1 template-body
If you uncomment the commented rows the output is:
  1 template-section
  1 template-body
  2 template-section
  2 template-body

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting an error? See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGcz. And if you remove that rogue DOCTYPE, then you do get the results you expect. See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGcz/1. Thanks!

Comment: @Václav Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: After removing DOCTYPE the result is the same (as I described). I use XSLT processor (xmlpatterns.exe) from Qt framework (www.qt.io).

Answer (score 0):

You talk of the *position() of current "section"*

That seems to suggest a misunderstanding, because position() is not a property of a node, it is a property of the list of nodes you are currently processing.

In your template with `match="section"`, the value of `position()` will be the position of the section you have matched within the list of nodes selected by the `xsl:apply-templates` instruction that caused this section to be selected. You haven't shown us this instruction, which suggests that you haven't appreciated its importance.

Some people make the mistake of thinking that `position()` returns the position of an element among its siblings. If that's what you want, it may be better to use `xsl:number`, or `count(preceding-sibling::XXXX)`.

Comment: This does not explain the described behavior where the value of the variable is correct within the `section` template.